# numpy apply_along_axis on a 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What happens when numpy.apply_along_axis takes a 1d array as input? When I use it on 1d array, I see something strange:

```
y=array([1,2,3,4])
```

First try:

```
apply_along_axis(lambda x: x > 2, 0, y)
apply_along_axis(lambda x: x - 2, 0, y)
```

returns:

```
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
array([-1,  0,  1,  2])
```

However when I try:

```
apply_along_axis(lambda x: x - 2 if x > 2 else x, 0, y)
```

I get an error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I could of course use list comprehension then convert back to array instead, but that seems convoluted and I feel like I'm missing something about apply_along_axis when applied to a 1d array.

**UPDATE**: as per Jeff G's answer, my confusion stems from the fact that for 1d array with only one axis, what is being passed to the function is in fact the 1d array itself rather than the individual elements.

"numpy.where" is clearly better for my chosen example (and no need for apply_along_axis), but my question is really about the proper idiom for applying a general function (that takes one scalar and returns one scalar) to each element of an array (other than list comprehension), something akin to pandas.Series.apply (or map). I know of 'vectorize' but it seems no less unwieldy than list comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm unclear whether you're asking if `y` must be 1-D (answer is no, it can be multidimensional) or if you're asking about the function passed into `apply_along_axis`.  To that, the answer is yes: the function you pass must take a 1-D array.  (This is stated clearly [in the function's documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)).

In your three examples, the `type` of `x` is always a 1-D array.  The reason your first two examples work is because Python is implicitly broadcasting the `>` and `-` operators along that array.

Your third example fails because there is no such broadcasting along an array for `if` / `else`.   For this to work with `apply_along_axis` you need to pass a function that takes a 1-D array.  `numpy.where` would work for this:

```
>>> apply_along_axis(lambda x: numpy.where(x > 2, x - 2, x), 0, y)
array([1, 2, 1, 2])
```

P.S. In all these examples, `apply_along_axis` is unnecessary, thanks to broadcasting. You could achieve the same results with these:

```
>>> y > 2
>>> y - 2
>>> numpy.where(y > 2, y - 2, y)
```

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my question slightly to be more precise, but you indeed answered my question anyway. However I have a follow up which is too long to put here, so I also added above in UPDATE.

Answer (score 3):

This answer addresses the updated addendum to your original question:

`numpy.vectorize` will take an elementwise function and return a new function. The new function can be applied to an entire array.  It's like `map`, but it uses the broadcasting rules of numpy.

```
f = lambda x: x - 2 if x > 2 else x # your elementwise fn
fv = np.vectorize(f)
fv(np.array([1,2,3,4]))
# Out[5]: array([1, 2, 1, 2])
```