# How can I change all value with same function in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume that there is sigmoid functions that I defined.

```py
def sigmoid(self, x):
   return something
```

I have arrays.

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I wanna make "a" like this:

```py
a =  [sigmoid(1), sigmoid(2), sigmoid(3), sigmoid(4), sigmoid(5), sigmoid(6)]
```

Is there anyway that don't use for loops? I mean, some numpy functions?

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35216364/6645624) answer

Comment: what does your sigmoid function do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy apply\_along\_axis on a 1d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557133/numpy-apply-along-axis-on-a-1d-array)

Comment: functions like `apply_along_axis` and `vectorize` are just as slow as loops.  `numpy` doesn't have tools to compile your Python function.  So whatever you do, it will end up calling `sigmoid` once for each element of  `a`.  That's where the time consumption is.  The "no loops" approach requires writing `sigmoid` itself to work with an array input.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the function manually

```py
a = np.array([sigmoid(1),sigmoid(2),..])
```

or using list-comprehension

```py
a = np.array([sigmoid(i+1) for i in range(6)])
```

But theres not, as far as I know, a specific numpy function that does it as such